# Access upsizing: Migrating queries that were designed to run locally

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a number of queries in a large legacy MS Access application that need to be moved to SQL Server. However, these queries were never designed to run in a shared context; most of them are recordsources for Access reports.

Embedded in most of the queries, are joins to a local `_ParameterInput` table that another developer created. This table is used to pass parameters into the Access queries. Being a local table, it's embedded in the frontend application, not the backend MDB. A large amount of code throughout the application assumes that the contents of the `_ParameterInput` table are specific for the current user.

My question is thus: What options do I have for migrating queries that depend on a local table like this? Here's what I've come up with so far:

1. Table-valued functions. I could (painfully) rewrite each query as a table-valued function so that parameters could be passed to it directly. There are several hundred queries that depend on local tables like this, so this route is less than ideal.
2. SQL Server temp table, with Access linked to it somehow. The existing local `_ParameterInput` table could become a link to `#ParameterInput` on the server. I don't know exactly how to initialize this on-the-fly, such that it would not need to be created by explicitly calling a stored procedure.

At the end of the day, I have to pick a solution that accomplishes the goal, but ideally I am looking for something that doesn't involve touching hundreds of queries and potentially thousands of VBA functions.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: First, I assume each user will have their own front-end and not share? You can still have the 'ParameterInput' table in the local copy and join with SQL Server. Not the best from a performance standpoint, but everything would continue to work as it does now. Is the local table 'joined' to other tables in the query, or just used to match a field value? How many fields in the local table (determines complexity)? You could convert to functions, but that may be a large task that is unnecessary. Depending on the way the table is used, you may be able to use VBA to change your queries for you.

Comment: Part of the upsizing project we are working on involves creating new front-end components as an ASP.NET MVC web site, using Entity Framework. EF needs to be able to pull the same results as Access when it queries the views that will be upsized.

Yes, each user has their own front-end, but my understanding is that if Access (JET engine) joins a local table and a linked table, it has to pull down the entire contents of the linked table to perform any filtering.

There are currently around 15 columns in this `_ParameterInput` table, but it grows when new reports/queries are implemented.

Comment: How are the fields in the local table updated? I had a similar issue some time ago and created a permanent SQL Server table that included the USER_ID. On the front-end I called a proc that updated the table with passed parameters if the USER_ID existed and created a new entry otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you can take a performance hit, but no idea about your environment and volume of data (now & future). You could migrate your table to SQL Server, add a column for 'user' or 'workstation', make changes to populate that field, then modify queries to also match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked off the comment from Ron Tornambe, this is effectively what I came up with. I renamed the existing table from `_ParameterInput` to `ParameterInput` (without underscore), then created a view to alias the table.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo._ParameterInput
AS
    SELECT * FROM [ParameterInput]
    WHERE [ParameterInput].[UserSID] = SUSER_SID();
```

I believe this approach should work well for what I needed, although I haven't done extensive testing yet.